# Python reading and printing text file

Tags: python, printing, readlines

I am reading in a text file and printing the contents, but am getting the below result, instead of line breaks, etc, which when opening the text file I can see, it is printing out \n along with other characters. How do I change the printing to reflect what the text file actually looks like? This is how I am reading in the text file:

```
infile = file("/path/to/log/file")
line = infile.readlines()
print line
```

This is the print I am getting:

'[2014-02-12 11:24:14 GMT]   INFO: Logging configured successfully.\n', '[2014-02-12 11:24:14 GMT]   INFO: iTMSTransporter : iTunes Store Transporter [1.7.9]\n', '[2014-02-12 11:24:14 GMT]   INFO: OS identifier: Mac OS X 10.9.1 (x86_64); jvm=24.0-b26; jre=1.7.0-internal-root_2012_12_05_20_29-b00\n', '[2014-02-12 11:24:14 GMT]   INFO: Memory: [JVM] 20M free, 31M total, 989M max [System] (Physical) 824M free, 8192M total (Swap) 1024M free, 1024M total\n', '[2014-02-12 11:24:14 GMT]

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
for line in infile:
  print line
```

What you were doing, calling infile.readlines(), gives you a list of all lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `'\n'` character *is* the line break. [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) will remove this and other whitespace for you:

```
for l in line:
    print(l.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want read file and close it:

```
with open("/path/to/log/file") as file_:
    for line in file_:
         print line.strip()
```